# print a hex number which have specified length use format string in python

Tags: python

I have a number 0x7fffffffd908(int representation) and I want it to align the length of machine address.

```
0x7fffffffd908 -> 0x00007fffffffd908
```

have any ways to achieve this only use format string?

I tried this :

```py
"{:0>#18x}"
```

but result is `00000x7fffffffd908`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
num = 140737488345352
print(f"{num:#018x}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format string

```
>>> "{0:#0{1}x}".format(0x7fffffffd908, 18)
0x00007fffffffd908
```

Which formats your value as hex, padded with leading `0`, to length 18.